# How can I use pipx version of a package by default?

Tags: python, pip, ansible, pipx

I'm on ubuntu 20.04 and trying to get my PC to use the `pipx` version of `ansible` by default, because the version installed by my package manager is too old.

I tried to use the instructions [here](https://lewoudar.medium.com/install-python-applications-globally-on-your-machine-63b8a9f00a0b) (amongst a lot of others) to get the new version of `ansible` to run when I type simply, "ansible", but it won't use that version.

```
user@pcname:~$ /home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/ansible/bin/ansible --version

ansible [core 2.13.13]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr
/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/ansible/lib/pyt
hon3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/user/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansi
ble/collections
  executable location = /home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/ansible/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Nov 22 2023, 10:22:35) [GCC 9.4.0]
  jinja version = 3.1.3
  libyaml = True

user@pcname:~$ ansible --version
bash: /home/user/.local/bin/ansible: No such file or directory

127 user@pcname:~$ ll /home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/ansible/bin/
total 276
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Feb  8 10:11 ./
drwxrwxr-x 6 user user 4096 Feb  2 18:22 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2202 Feb  8 10:11 activate
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1254 Feb  8 10:11 activate.csh
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2406 Feb  8 10:11 activate.fish
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 8834 Feb  8 10:11 Activate.ps1
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  248 Feb  2 18:22 ansible*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  268 Feb  2 18:23 ansible-community*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  249 Feb  2 18:22 ansible-config*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  278 Feb  2 18:22 ansible-connection*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  250 Feb  2 18:22 ansible-console*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  246 Feb  2 18:22 ansible-doc*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  249 Feb  2 18:22 ansible-galaxy*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  252 Feb  2 18:22 ansible-inventory*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  251 Feb  2 18:22 ansible-playbook*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  247 Feb  2 18:22 ansible-pull*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 1732 Feb  2 18:22 ansible-test*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  248 Feb  2 18:22 ansible-vault*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  263 Feb  2 18:22 easy_install*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  263 Feb  2 18:22 easy_install-3.8*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  253 Feb  8 10:11 pip*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  253 Feb  8 10:11 pip3*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user  253 Feb  8 10:11 pip3.8*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user    7 Feb  2 18:10 python -> python3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user   16 Feb  2 18:10 python3 -> /usr/bin/python3*

user@pcname:~$ apt-cache policy ansible
ansible:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.10.0-1ppa~focal
  Version table:
     5.10.0-1ppa~focal 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Pac
kages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu focal/main i386 Pack
ages
     2.9.6+dfsg-1 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages

user@pcname:~$ ansible
bash: /home/user/.local/bin/ansible: No such file or directory

127 user@pcname:~$ ansible --version
bash: /home/user/.local/bin/ansible: No such file or directory

127 user@pcname:~$ which ansible
/usr/bin/ansible

user@pcname:~$ whereis ansible
ansible: /usr/bin/ansible /etc/ansible /usr/share/ansible /usr/share/man/man1/an
sible.1.gz

user@pcname:~$ pip install --user pipx
Requirement already satisfied: pipx in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.12.3.1)
DEPRECATION: mythtv 31.0.-1 has a non-standard version number. pip 24.0 will enf
orce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to upgrade to a newer vers
ion of mythtv or contact the author to suggest that they release a version with
a conforming version number. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/
pip/issues/12063

user@pcname:~$ pipx ensurepath
Your PATH looks like it already is set up for pipx. Pass `--force` to modify the
 PATH.

user@pcname:~$ pipx list
venvs are in /home/user/.local/pipx/venvs
binaries are exposed on your $PATH at /home/user/.local/bin
   package ansible 6.7.0, Python 3.8.10
    - ansible-community
   package ansible-core 2.13.13, Python 3.8.10
    - __init__.py
    - ansible_connection_cli_stub.py
    - ansible (symlink not installed)
    - ansible-config (symlink not installed)
    - ansible-connection (symlink not installed)
    - ansible-console (symlink not installed)
    - ansible-doc (symlink not installed)
    - ansible-galaxy (symlink not installed)
    - ansible-inventory (symlink not installed)
    - ansible-playbook (symlink not installed)
    - ansible-pull (symlink not installed)
    - ansible-test (symlink not installed)
    - ansible-vault (symlink not installed)

user@pcname:~$ ll /home/user/.local/bin/ansible*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 59 Feb  2 18:23 /home/user/.local/bin/ansible-communit
y -> /home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/ansible/bin/ansible-community*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 77 Feb  2 18:12 /home/user/.local/bin/ansible_connecti
on_cli_stub.py -> /home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/ansible-core/bin/ansible_connect
ion_cli_stub.py
```

I suppose it's not working because of those "symlink not installed" messages but I don't know how to fix it.

Edit:

```
user@pcname:~$ ll /usr/bin/ansible
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5915 Oct 26  2022 /usr/bin/ansible*

user@pcname:~$ /usr/bin/ansible --version
ansible [core 2.12.10]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/user/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Nov 22 2023, 10:22:35) [GCC 9.4.0]
  jinja version = 3.1.3
  libyaml = True
```

Comment: In a new terminal, what is the output of `which ansible`? Is there a `~/.local/bin/ansible` symlink? If so, where does it point?

Comment: @larsks That's in the code block I posted. `/usr/bin/ansible`. I made an edit with the version info for that at the end of my question.

Comment: @larsks There is no `~/.local/bin/ansible` symlink.

Comment: You need to learn about the "`PATH` environment variable" and how to use it. It is not specific to Ansible, or pipx, or Python.

Comment: @sinoroc I think I know what a `PATH` is for, but please elucidate me. Do you think I should add `/home/user/.local/pipx/venvs/ansible/bin/` to my `PATH`? I assume that would solve the specific problem here, but doesn't explain why `pipx` didn't do that automatically, if it is needed.

Comment: There is `pipx ensurepath` command that can help. At the end you should inspect the order in which the directory paths are listed in the `PATH` environment variable. Make sure that the path for the directory of the `ansible` command you want is listed before the one you do not want.